# Make a string with a UTC+1 date aware

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.utils.timezone import make_aware

str_date = "02-05-2020 15:59" # UTC+1
dt = make_aware(datetime.strptime(str_date, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M'))
print(dt)
```

Using the above code which prints 2020-05-02 15:59:00+00:00. Shouldn't it subtract 1 hour and print 2020-05-02 14:59:00+00:00?

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC' and USE_TZ = True in settings.py.

This subtracts 1 hour from my Ubuntu machine date

```
from django.utils import timezone

now = timezone.now()
print(now)
```

Comment: How would it know that it's UTC+1? You just wrote that as a comment. By default `make_aware()` uses your default time zone, which you said was UTC.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry It's the same time format as my machine which is UTC+1.

Comment: The operating system's time has nothing to do with parsing a date, though. You wrote out a date time string, converted it into a naive datetime, and then asked Django to make it aware using the UTC time zone. So UTC+1 doesn't come into it. See the documentation for `make_aware()` if you want to use a different time zone.

Comment: Were you able to solve it? I provided an answer below

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `tzinfo` attribute using `datetime.replace`

```
    from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta

    offset = {'hours':1}
    str_date = "02-05-2020 15:59" # UTC+1

    unaware_dt = datetime.strptime(str_date, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')  
    # datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 2, 15, 59)

    aware_dt = unaware_dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone(timedelta(**offset)))  
    # datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 2, 15, 59, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0, 3600)))
```

To validate, see its offset vs the same time but in UTC

```
   import pytz
   difference = unaware_dt.replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC) - aware_dt
   print(difference.seconds) # 3600 seconds or 1 hour
```